# Random Name To Exact File In Android

Tags: android, random

I need to generate random name to exact file in android programmatically.I mean that every time java runs the code it should generate random name not to overwrite the old one.Can i achieve that?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that. Anything is possible if you put your mind to it.

Comment: :)Yeah lets now get to code:) whats the code for it?you see i need that because I'm sending captured image to server,and i need before that generate random name for server side not to be overwritten the file

Comment: why not generate the name on the server side? Maybe make it time based

Comment: Im too weak for server side i need to do all that in java

Comment: You can use a combination of date and time (YYYY-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss) to generate a unique file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it pretty easily.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_" + ".jpg";

    File dir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File file= new File(dir, imageFileName);

}
```

Comment: MAN i Love ya it worked yeah thanks alot  i appreciate

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you but can you help me to provide with your code.How i point to my file which should be renamed randomly with your code?

Comment: i didn't really understand but you should point a file using the `File` class. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Comment: ok like to get external directory point to file with string value and add it to place where your code says timeStamp?